# How to disable narrowing conversion warnings?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, gcc4.7, compiler-options

I use `-Wall` and updating to new gcc I have got a lot of `warning: narrowing conversion`. I want to disable them, but leave all other warnings untouched (ideally).

I can find nothing about `narrowing` in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

How to disable narrowing conversion warnings?
Is it possible at all?

P.S.

1. I need to Disable warnings, not fix them in the source code.
2. Blind `-Wno-conversion` doesn't help.

Comment: You mean you even get them if you write explicit typecasts?

Comment: @MrLister, no, I need a quick "fix".

Comment: Oh, so no rewriting of code? Then I misunderstood, sorry.

Comment: oh. it feels like it is easier to fix them....

Comment: _“I have got a lot of `warning: narrowing conversion`”_: Ok, for what code? Is that the exact complete warning message? _“I can find nothing about `narrowing` in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html”_: Well I can find an instance of “`-Wnarrowing`”. Did you try `-Wno-narrowing`?

Comment: The newer versions of gcc tend to write the warning option used to enable the warning as part of the warning. You just need to inject a `no-` at the obvious place. I think it is `-Wno-narrowing`.

Comment: Ran into the same issue in gcc4.4.7.  It turns out the -Wno-narrowing flag has been broken for a while because it's gone back and forth on whether the condition should trigger a warning (prior to and after 4.6) or an error (4.6).  (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783).  There's no way around it without modifying the code.

Answer (score 32):

As gx_ said, adding `-Wno-narrowing` to your command line should ignore those errors.  Encountered this myself when upgrading to C++0x.

Comment: It worked!!
Was stuck trying to install CTCdecoder on the new MacBook M1 for 2 days!!

Answer (score 4):

As a small FYI, as detailed on https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wnarrowing this is an alias for -Wno-c++11-narrowing (there are multiple narrowing warning flags)

Answer (score 0):

try this option
-Wno-error=narrowing